# import stripe web_1 | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe' using docker for django

Tags: django, docker, django-views, stripe-payments

I am using django in docker container. I install stripe with this command `docker-compose exec web pipenv install stripe==2.32.0` . This gave me successful message also. then I did docker down and rebuild. this is my view file

```
# orders/views.py
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY


class OrdersPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/purchase.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): # new
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['stripe_key'] = settings.STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        return context


def charge(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=3900,
            ncy='usd',
            description='Purchase all books',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
    return render(request, 'orders/charge.html')
```

The error I'am getting

```
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "/code/orders/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
web_1  |     from .views import OrdersPageView
web_1  |   File "/code/orders/views.py", line 2, in <module>
web_1  |     import stripe
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'
```

this is my pip file

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
django-allauth = "*"
pillow = "*"
stripe = "==2.32.0"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. Please answer If someone know or faced this before

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your image's `Dockerfile`?  You wouldn't usually install packages using `docker-compose exec`, since those changes will get lost as soon as the container is deleted (which is a pretty routine operation).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem as well. @DavidMaze is right, running `docker-compose up -d --build` rebuilds the container and installs all packages in your Pipfile.